# laravel buttons move unintentionally

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, bootstrap-4

Three buttons are provided and each has a different role

```
<div class="form-group row mb-0">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                {{ __('update') }}
            </button>
            <button type="button" onclick="reset()" class="btn btn-primary">
                {{ __('reset')   }}
            </button>
            <button type="button" onclick="history.back()" class="btn btn-primary">
                {{ __('Cancel') }}
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But they all do the same thing
All go to form action

```
<form id="projectName" action="{{ route('project.update', ['id' => $param->id]) }}" method="post">
```

How can I make all values ​​blank in javascript and use back?

```
<script>
function reset() {
    // document.getElementById("project_name").innerHTML = "";
    document.forms["projectName"].name.project_name.value = "";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Try returning false from the reset function in the end.

Comment: @MatJ Did not return

Comment: You can use  location.reload(); ******

 function reset() {
 location.reload(); 

}

Comment: @su3158, I mean, you need to add `return false;` as the last line in `reset()` function.

Comment: @MatJ Still works the same as submit

Comment: @mukeshkumar Still works the same as send

Comment: Did you check ?

Comment: @mukeshkumar Of course

Comment: Can't you just use `<input type="reset">`?

Comment: @TimothyKruger I couldn't use it and tried
Then it was done

Comment: @su3158 glad you managed to get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not giving the button type then it will take the type as **submit** by default.

So instead of keep empty the type of button, you can set the `type="button"`